# How can multiple variables be used to create multiple jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, addclass

When I convert multiple variables into multiple selectors the below code fails to execute.

### DEMO HERE

```
$('.Btn').on('click', function () {
  var outer = $(this).data('test');
  var inner = $(outer).children('.Inner');
  $(outer + ',' + inner).addClass('Success');
});
```

In the code above:

**This is successful**

```
$(outer).addClass('Success');
```

**This is successful**

```
$(inner).addClass('Success');
```

**This is not**

```
$(outer + ',' + inner).addClass('Success');
```

---

**QUESTION**

How can multiple variables be used to create multiple jquery selectors?

Comment: That doesn't work because `inner` is not a string but an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latter method will only work if both variables contain strings. In your case you need to use `add()` to join the objects held in the variables together:

```
$(outer).add(inner).addClass('Success');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L5v4mL8t/5/)

Answer (score 1):

In you script, outer is a string, but inner is a jQuery object. You can't connect these values to each other. Of course, you can get the inner class name as a string, but it's a bit tricky and not always work well...

If you must have the +','+ syntax, here's the solution, but as I mentioned, it's really hacky:

```
$('.Btn').on('click', function () {
    var outer = $(this).data('test');
    var inner = '.'+$(outer).children('.Inner').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $(outer+', '+inner).addClass('Success');
});
```

A better solution if you handle the inner div with something like add() or find().